# PhantomJS when calling from PHP return blank page else running fine

Tags: php, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am using PHP to call a phantomjs script, but it is returning blank output. Though its all running fine on console.

Here is my JS file:

```
var page = new WebPage();
var system = require('system');
page.open("https://www.groupon.com/goods", function(){
    var events = page.evaluate(function(){
        return $('.deal-card').map(function(e){ 
           return '* ' + this.innerText
        }).toArray().join('\n');
    });

    console.log('Upcoming Events in Oxfordshire:');
    console.log(events);

   phantom.exit();
});
```

And here is my PHP

```
$script = "C:/phantomjs-2.0.0/bin/price1.js";
$response = exec("C:/phantomjs-2.0.0/bin/phantomjs $script", $output);

print_r($response);
Print_r(implode(",,",$output));
```

Comment: I copied the code and it works. maybe it has to do with your phantomjs configuration.

Comment: Or a security issue.

Comment: Thanks @winner_joiner I have reinstalled phantomjs and XAMPP on my system both latest.

Comment: You are correct, because before these new installs things were fine

Comment: It is waiting too long for local host and then after long wait returns blank

Comment: have you tried executing hte php-script on the commandline? just to see if the script works? Which php version are you using?

Comment: Yes on command line also its giving blank, version is 5.5.28

Comment: Thanks @winner_joiner, the issue was with PHP version, I was using 5.5.28, that was giving problems. Now I changed to PHP 5.5.9, that fixed it.

Comment: Just write your findings in an answer and get yourself the selflearner badge. :)

Comment: Sure, thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing and good suggestions. I found a solution to this issue.

The issue was related to the version of PHP, The PHP version 5.5.28 was giving blank output. After changing version to 5.5.9 the output is started getting displayed on my Web page.